# jquery: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem when I try to submit my form to an action on my server side code which looks like this:

```
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public async Task<ActionResult> DoRegister(UserRegistrationViewModel model)
   {
     // Some code here
   }
```

The form contains Html.AntiForgeryToken() as well so this isn't an issue. The jQuery code looks like following:

```
 $('form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if ($(this).valid()) {

            StartLoading();
            var formdata = new FormData($(this).get(0));
            $.post("/User/DoRegister",formdata, function (data) {
                $(".registerLoader").fadeOut("fast");
                if (data.statusCode == 200) {
                    window.location.href = "/Plans";
                }
                else if (data.statusCode == 100) {
                    $("body").html(data.View);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
```

When I try to submit the form I get the following error:

```
jquery: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

What am I doing wrong here? Can someone help me out?

Comment: Can you show what data *formdata* contains?

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain sure one moment

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain how can I read contents of form data? When I do a console.log(formdata); I get this: FormData {}
__proto__: FormData
append: ƒ append()
delete: ƒ delete()
entries: ƒ entries()
forEach: ƒ forEach()
get: ƒ ()
getAll: ƒ getAll()
has: ƒ has()
keys: ƒ keys()
set: ƒ ()
values: ƒ values()
constructor: ƒ FormData()

Comment: Anyone guys ? =)

Comment: Just a sidenote `$(this).get(0)` is the same as `this` - you turn a dom object into a jquery object just to get the dom object again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing an HTML element instead of its value. You can use `serializeArray`

```
var formdata = $("form").serializeArray();
```

> The .serializeArray() method creates a JavaScript array of objects, ready to be encoded as a JSON string. It operates on a jQuery collection of forms and/or form controls.

Comment: Yes thats it !!! I figured it out and wanted to post but yes this is the solution !! :)